# Android Gallery Full SIze

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am trying to implement scroll type gallery for my app.(Just like the full size image browser we get on default android gallery.)

What I am getting [image]

instead I want the gallery image to be displayed on the entire screen.

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_arrow_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_disabled" />

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_arrow_imageview"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_arrow_imageview"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:spacing="20dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_arrow_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_enabled" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the main relative layout to `fill_parent` and the ImageView to `match_parent`.

Comment: By the way, why do you want to use Gallery? It is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) since API 16. I suggest to use ViewPager, like in this [tutorial](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/).